# How do I access a variable in PHP inside a foreach loop?

Tags: php, laravel, goutte

I am **webscraping** a table from [this link](https://www.worldometers.info/world-population/population-by-country/) using the [Goute Library](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte) in php.

Below is my code

```
    $client = new Client();
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.worldometers.info/world-population/population-by-country/');
    $crawler->filter('#example2 tbody')->filter('tr')->each(function ($node) {

       $country = new Country(); // I have declared country here.
       $test = "TOday";   //I have a variable Test

        $node->filter('td')->each(function ($td,$i){

            switch ($i){
                case 1:
                    $country_name = $td->text();

                    echo $test; //I cannot access test here.
                    $country->name = $country_name; //I am not able to access the declared Country here

                    break;
                case 2:
                    //todo case 2
                    break;
                case 3:
                    //todo case 3
                    break;
                case 4:
                    //todo case 4
                    break;
            }
        });

        echo "<br><br><br>";

    });
```

My code contains two foreach loops. Inside the first loop I am declaring variable $test and $country which I would like to access inside my second loop.

However, whenever I try to access the variables, I am getting the error :

> "Undefined variable: test"

Below is a screenshot from PhpStorm.
[image]

Why am I not able to access these variables which have clearly been declared and even initialized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to access this variables iniside your  function clouser, you should tell that function to use them:

```
 $crawler->filter('#example2 tbody')->filter('tr')->each(function ($node)use( $country) {

   $country = new Country(); // I have declared country here.
   $test = "TOday";   //I have a variable Test
```

if you have another vaiable you want to use, just add it to function argument:

```
->each(function ($node)use( $country,$secondVariable,$thirdVariable ...)
```